# DotNetNuke: how to use DotNetNuke modules in my own site?

Tags: dotnetnuke

We're developing a web site using ASP.NET and one feature is managing user uploaded files. We're recommended that DotNetNuke is one of the best file management tools in the DotNet world.

However, we don't want all features of DotNetNuke, specifically, we want the Document Library module only.

Is it possible to embed the module in my own site?
Please recommend any document or link.
Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Zach@Shine

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to run a module from DotNetNuke without having DotNetNuke there to host the module.  They have hard-set dependencies on the core.

Answer (score 0):

They are developed and intended to use in Dotnetnuke.

If they would be able to cope up with our own ASP .net website, they would have been 'Web Applications' not Modules.

Why don't u shift over your website to DNN. It's really nice platform to work on, given that you are working for ASP .net website.

Ravi